# Filter rows with condition and drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, if-statement

I have a big data set and I need to filter it with a condition but the problem that the condition can be true for multiple days for the same ID as you can see in the example below.

```
Date            ID             Col1            Col2   
2-18-2019       1            ap sd n1           23
2-18-2019       2            dh au n1           88
2-18-2019       3            ap hre n1          92
2-19-2019       1            sd n1 df           23
2-19-2019       2            sf ap n1           78
2-19-2019       3            ap sdv n1          78
2-20-2019       1            ap d3 fg           37
2-20-2019       2            sd ap n1           29
2-20-2019       3            djd dh n1          34
2-21-2019       1            eds ed sd          44
2-21-2019       2            u4r rg ap          34
2-21-2019       3            ufif ew            23
2-22-2019       1            eds sd             44
2-22-2019       2            u4r rg             34
2-22-2019       3            ap ew n1           23
~~~
3-10-2019       2            ap gh n1           78
3-10-2019       3            sd dv n1           78
3-10-2019       1            ap d3 n1           37
3-11-2019       2            sd ap n1           29
3-11-2019       3            djt rh n1          34
~~~
3-21-2019       1            n1 ed sd           44
3-21-2019       2            fg td df           34
3-21-2019       3            ufg yt ew          23
3-22-2019       1            bvs sd n1          44
3-22-2019       2            u4r ap g           34
3-22-2019       3            ap ew n1           23
```

And the code look like this

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\~\SallesDB.csv")
df = df.astype(str)
df = df[(df.Col1.str.contains('ap') & df.Col1.str.contains('n1')) | (df.Col1.str.contains('sd') & df.Col1.str.contains('n1'))]
```

and the result looks like this:

```
Date            ID             Col1            Col2   
2-18-2019       1            ap sd n1           23
2-18-2019       3            ap hre n1          92
2-19-2019       1            sd n1 df           23
2-19-2019       2            sf ap n1           78
2-19-2019       3            ap sdv n1          78
2-20-2019       2            sd ap n1           29
2-22-2019       3            ap ew n1           23
~~~
3-10-2019       2            ap gh n1           78
3-10-2019       3            sd dv n1           78
3-10-2019       1            ap d3 n1           37
3-11-2019       2            sd ap n1           29
~~~
3-21-2019       1            n1 ed sd           44
3-22-2019       1            bvs sd n1          44
3-22-2019       3            ap ew n1           23+
```

And I have tried the solution below but it didn't work since Col1 is not exactly the same

```
df = df[(df.Col1.str.contains('ap') & df.Col1.str.contains('n1')) | (df.Col1.str.contains('sd') & df.Col1.str.contains('n1'))].drop_duplicates('Col1', keep='last')
```

And the result I wanted should  look for ap and n1 OR sd and n1 , but make sure its not repeated in the Next day, the condition should be: if [ID] == [ID] & [Col2] == [Col2] AND [Col1] contains ('ap'&'n1 OR 'sd'&'n1' is true for 2 days (for example 2-18-2019 And 2-19-2019) keep first.
And the result I need should look like this:

```
Date            ID             Col1            Col2   
2-18-2019       1            ap sd n1           23
2-18-2019       3            ap hre n1          92
2-19-2019       2            sf ap n1           78
2-22-2019       3            ap ew n1           23
~~~
3-10-2019       2            ap gh n1           78
3-10-2019       3            sd dv n1           78
3-10-2019       1            ap d3 n1           37
~~~
3-21-2019       1            n1 ed sd           44
3-22-2019       3            ap ew n1           23+
```

I have looking for a way to do it for too long and couldn't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom `filter` function which will remove next date if it exists for that id, I used [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#:%7E:text=apply,-GroupBy.&text=Apply%20function%20func%20group%2Dwise,a%20series%20or%20a%20scalar.) and [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

**Working of custom filter:**

I used groupby to group based on `ID` column then I iterated that group by using apply method. In my filter function I am adding +1 dates and then comparing if they exists in current group and then filtering them to get your desired result.
For ex if there are `date = [20-02-2021,21-02-2021]` for `ID 1` then adding +1 would be result in `date_plus_1 = [21-02-2021,22-02-2021]` then removing rows which contain rows in `date_plus_1` which means removing `21-02-2021`

```
import pandas as pd
import io

#datasource ignore
data = io.StringIO('''
Date,ID,Col1,Col2
2-18-2019,1,ap sd n1,23
2-18-2019,2,dh au n1,88
2-18-2019,3,ap hre n1,92
2-19-2019,1,sd n1 df,23
2-19-2019,2,sf ap n1,78
2-19-2019,3,ap sdv n1,78
2-20-2019,1,ap d3 fg,37
2-20-2019,2,sd ap n1,29
2-20-2019,3,djd dh n1,34
2-21-2019,1,eds ed sd,44
2-21-2019,2,u4r rg ap,34
2-21-2019,3,ufif ew,23
2-22-2019,1,eds sd,44
2-22-2019,2,u4r rg,34
2-22-2019,3,ap ew n1,23
3-10-2019,2,ap gh n1,78
3-10-2019,3,sd dv n1,78
3-10-2019,1,ap d3 n1,37
3-11-2019,2,sd ap n1,29
3-11-2019,3,djt rh n1,34
3-21-2019,1,n1 ed sd,44
3-21-2019,2,fg td df,34
3-21-2019,3,ufg yt ew,23
3-22-2019,1,bvs sd n1,44
3-22-2019,2,u4r ap g,34
3-22-2019,3,ap ew n1,23
''')

df = pd.read_csv(data)

#Conditions
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df[(df.Col1.str.contains('ap') & df.Col1.str.contains('n1')) | (df.Col1.str.contains('sd') & df.Col1.str.contains('n1'))]

#solution
from datetime import timedelta
def filter(grp):
  f = grp.Date + timedelta(days=1)
  return grp[~grp.Date.isin(f)]

df.groupby(['ID']).apply(filter).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
Date    ID  Col1    Col2
0   2019-02-18  1   ap sd n1    23
1   2019-03-10  1   ap d3 n1    37
2   2019-03-21  1   n1 ed sd    44
3   2019-02-19  2   sf ap n1    78
4   2019-03-10  2   ap gh n1    78
5   2019-02-18  3   ap hre n1   92
6   2019-02-22  3   ap ew n1    23
7   2019-03-10  3   sd dv n1    78
8   2019-03-22  3   ap ew n1    23
```

Comment: Hi @k33da_the_bug thank you for your answer and  logically it would work but unfortunately it didn't work when I applied it. actually it didn't change at all it still return the same result with my code. do you have any idea why? P.s: I haven't use io since my data is in csv file that has thousands of data

Comment: io.StringIO I used that for just parsing your text data. You don't need to do that step just use `pd.read_csv('your_file,url_or_data',...other params)`.  Also I wanted to know if there are any missing values in your actual data?

Comment: well I have mentioned in the question that not only ID==ID but also Col2==Col2. and I have missed mentioning that i actually used groupby ` df.groupby(['ID', 'Col2'])['Col2']`